# How do I Check if an Alarm is Currently Set?

Tags: c

I am trying to program a simple C application that takes user input and sets an `alarm()` based on it. However, if there is already an alarm set, I don't want the user to overwrite it, so I need a way to check if an alarm has been set without overwriting the current alarm. How could I do this?

Comment: Use a flag to track it down?

Comment: Have you read `man 2 alarm` so far? While at it, also take a look at `setitimer()` and `getitimer()`.

Comment: I've read man 2 alarm, but it seems the only ways to check if there is an alarm currently set, which is by calling the alarm function again, reset the current alarm.

Comment: A flag may work, I'll try it out.

Comment: @Br0f1st There is one interesting line in that man: `alarm() and setitimer(2) share the same timer; calls to one will interfere with use of the other`. And when you look at `man setitimer`, you see also `getitimer()`. Does it help somehow?

Comment: If you're the one setting the alarms() in the first place, why can't you just keep track of them yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag withing the your `struct` and set it when you set the alarm. Before setting the alarm make sure the flag is not already set. Make sure that everytime when you create a new alarm clock i.e. object of your structure, set the flag value to zero indicating that it's not set at the start.

```
typedef struct AlarmClock {
      Time startTime;
      //Any other fields that you want
      int isSet;
}AC;



//Try to set the alarm and returns the status
 boolean setAlarm(AC *ac,Time time) {
    if(ac->isSet) {
        //Alarm is alreadyt set. Return false
        return false;
    }
    ac->startTime = time;
    ac->isSet= 1;
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: I didn't check it, but if `getitimer()` can return timer set by `alarm()`, why keeping extra flag? Is there amy benefits in this approach? Well, maybe it saves one context switch, but is it worth it?

Comment: You can't set alarm to negative value as `alarm()` takes `unsigned int` argument. When you need to cancel your alarm you need to provide 0 to `alarm()` call. And that's how you know from `getitimer()` that there is no pending alarm set. So you would loose your value anyway, whether you decided to use `getitimer()` or not. Now, the original question wasn't about keeping different alarm settings, but rather author was asking how to check if alarm currently set. The answer is to use `getitimer()` call, it seems to be the most straightforward way to do that. But again, I didn't check it personally